# Sistema de Agendamento Exército Brasileiro

Tags: php

Estou com um problema um tanto perturbador, já pesquisei tentei de varias formas, mas não achei solução.

Abaixo a explicação:

Um sistema bem simples, ele parece com um calendário, porem dentro da cada dia do calendário,
existe 3 campos em `checkbox` para serem clicados, nesses campos usei a nomenclatura de C, A, J (Café, Almoço e Jantar) e também tornei clicável o numero do dia.

ficando da seguinte forma:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Com esse sistema o Militar consegue agendar o dia que ele vai comer na cozinha.

O problema que estou tendo é que quando ele seleciona mais de 1 numero de dia o resultado aparece todo duplicado, assim:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Segue abaixo o código:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sistema de Arranchamento</title>
    <?php
    /*include "conectando.php"; */
        date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

         $dates = date('Y/m/d');
         $hoje = getdate(strtotime($dates));
         $ultimoDia = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,
                                       $hoje['mon'],
                                       $hoje['year']);

        $primeiraSemana = (($hoje['wday'] + 1) -
                          ($hoje['mday'] - ((int)($hoje['mday'] / 6) * 7))) % 7;

    ?>

    <style>

        td[data-semana="0"] { color: #000000; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Estamos em <?= $hoje['year'] ?></h1>
    <p><?= sprintf('Hoje é dia <strong>%0d / %0d</strong>, agora são %02d horas e %0d minutos.',
                   $hoje['mday'], $hoje['mon'], $hoje['hours'], $hoje['minutes'])
    ?></p>

    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Dom</th>
            <th>Seg</th>
            <th>Ter</th>
            <th>Qua</th>
            <th>Qui</th>
            <th>Sex</th>
            <th>Sáb</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
    <form action="checkbox.php" method="post">
        <?php
        for($semana = 0; $semana < $primeiraSemana; ++$semana) {
            echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
        }
        for($dia = 1; $dia < $ultimoDia; ++$dia) {
            if( $semana > 6 ) {
                $semana = 0;
                echo '</tr><tr>';
            }

            echo "<td data-semana=\"$semana\"><center><font size='2px'/>";
            echo "$dia <input type='checkbox' name='dia[]' value='$dia'> <center><input type='checkbox' name='opcao[]' value='C'>C <input type='checkbox' name='opcao[]' value='A'>A <input type='checkbox' name='opcao[]' value='J'>J</td>";
            ++$semana;
        }
        for(; $semana < 7; ++$semana) {
            echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
        }

        ?>

    <?php
if( !empty( $_POST['dias'] ) ) {
    foreach( $_POST['dias'] as $key => $value ) {
        echo "<br />Semana $key<br />";
        foreach( $value as $dias ) {
            echo "$dias<br />";
        }
    }
}
?>

    <input type=submit value="Arranchar">
       </form>
        </tr>

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**checkbox.php**

```
<?php
// Verifica se usuário escolheu algum número

if(isset($_POST["dia"])){
   if(isset($_POST["opcao"])){ 


     echo "Você se arranchou para os dias:<BR>";

     // Faz loop pelo array dos numeros
     foreach($_POST["dia"] as $dia){
       foreach($_POST["opcao"] as $numero){


        echo " - " . $dia . " -" . $numero . "</BR>";
       }
     } 
   }
}
else
{
    echo "Você não se arranchou para nenhum dia!<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Dá  um print_r($_POST); pra ver o que retorna pra você...

Comment: O erro está no forach do checkbox.. porque você está fazendo dois foreach.. por isso duplica mesmo :)

Comment: O problema é que os dias têm de estar associados as outras checkbox

Comment: Assim que o bloqueio da pergunta terminar, em cerca de 45 minutos, por favor, edite a pergunta para mudar qualquer tipo de informação que lhe prejudique, mas sem que invalide as respostas. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Consegui resolver o seu problema com *array* bidimensional, porque tens de saber qual o dia escolhido e quis refeições associadas a esse dia.

```
echo "$dia 
<input type='checkbox' name='"; echo "arrachar[$dia][dia]";    echo"' value='$dia'> <center>
<input type='checkbox' name='"; echo "arrachar[$dia][opcaoC]"; echo"' value='C'>C 
<input type='checkbox' name='"; echo "arrachar[$dia][opcaoA]"; echo"' value='A'>A 
<input type='checkbox' name='"; echo "arrachar[$dia][opcaoJ]"; echo"' value='J'>J</td>";
```

E no **checkbox.php**:

```
if(isset($_POST["arrachar"]))
{
    echo "Você se arranchou para os dias:<BR>";

    foreach($_POST["arrachar"] as $infos)
    {
        if(count($infos)==1) //verifica se tem alguma refeição marcada
                continue;
        $first = 1;
        foreach($infos as $info)
        {
            if($first == 1) //primeiro elemento do array é o dia.
            {
                echo "No dia $info";
                $first = 0;
            }
            else
                echo "e refeição $info";
            echo "<br>";
        }
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

[Veja aqui o exemplo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/c95d-nuks)

Answer (score 0):

Elabore o foreach desta forma:
Da forma que você fez, está duplicado... Pode passar um parametro só.

```
foreach($_POST as $key){
    echo "{$key->dia} - {$key->opcao}";
}
```

Comment: Acho que assim não funciona...

Comment: Porque cada dia pode ter mais de uma opção...

Comment: Faça o teste. Eu normalmente pego o post e coloco dentro do foreach para buscar as arrays que eu quero, independente de quantas sejam para cada dia..

Comment: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/uwsx-rcv7

Comment: Tem de ser com array bidimensional para associar as opções aos dias...

Comment: Conseguiu elaborar?